# list.UpdateList method throwing an Exception "Microsoft.Sharepoint.SoapServerException"

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I want to modify File/List MetaData of Sharepoint.

For that i am using `List.UpdateList()` method.

But it is throwing an exception:

> Microsoft.Sharepoint.SoapServerException

I am using admin account. And using List web service.

Can i get some good examples of modifying Metadata of SharePoint document using c# (Web Services).

Answer (score 2):

The below article has a got examples to update list item using web service [Updating List Item](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2007/09/19/updating-list-information-in-sharepoint-via-web-services.aspx)